# Calculating Average length of words using while loop

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to solve a python textbook problem: The chapter is loops so I am pretty sure it wants me to use it and not any other advanced methods.

Write a program with a loop that repeatedly asks the user to enter a word. The user should enter nothing (press Enter without typing anything) to signal the end of the loop. Once the loop ends, the program should display the average length of the words entered, rounded to the nearest whole number.

My code:

```
total = 0
num_words = 0

input_word = input('Please enter a word or press enter to quit: ')


while input_word != '':
    input_word = input('Please enter a word or press enter to quit: ')
    length_word = len(input_word)
    total += length_word
    num_words += 1



avg = total/num_words

print('Average length of word is:',avg)
```

If I enter two words, the number of words are correctly reflecting as 2 but the total number of characters in the word are only counting for the second input. I am guess the first input to prime the while loop is not getting adding to total length of characters. How should I fix this ?

Comment: why do you need to prime the while loop?

Comment: Just set `input_word = 'dummy'` or something to prime the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are overwriting `input_word` as soon as it enters into the `while` loop.

Secondly, `num_words` is added 1 even when you *press enter*. So when you say number of words are correct, it is actually **not** counting the very first `input_word`, but rather from second `input_word` to `press enter to quit`.

Changing as follow make it work:

```
total = 0
num_words = 0

input_word = input('Please enter a word or press space to quit: ')

while input_word != '':
    length_word = len(input_word)
    total += length_word
    num_words += 1
    input_word = input('Please enter a word or press enter to quit: ')

avg = total/num_words

print('Average length of word is:',avg)
```

Comment: You are right. In the second iteration of while loop, input_word is assigned to no space, so word length for that iteration is 0 but num_words will still add to the total. So if input_word is assigned to '' at the end of the loop, the next iteration won't happen when it first checks the condition again.

Answer (score 0):

You are discarding the first value in the first step of your loop. Change the *priming* value to something like

```
input_word = "foo"
```

and subtract `1` from `num_words` not to count the empty string:

```
avg = total / (num_words - 1)
```

Sample output:

```
Please enter a word or press enter to quit: abc
Please enter a word or press enter to quit: de
Please enter a word or press enter to quit:
Average length of word is: 2.5
```